# Simulating MessageBox.Show()

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, messagebox

I'm Writing a program in `WPF`(c#). I live in Iran so my language is persian(`right to left`). I want to make a custom `MessageBox` with more buttons or another controls.

I use a simple `Window` to show messages. In C# when MessageBox is showing, user can not click or do any thing with another windows. How can I `simulate` this, in my window?

*In pervious I used WPFCustomeMessageBox library. please do not refer it to me.*

Comment: You can use `Window.ShowDialog` to obtain a modal dialog. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.window_methods.aspx).

Comment: @bash.d That doesn't address the issue with aligning text as Right-to-Left, which is the reason he is using something other than MessageBox in the first place.

Comment: Buddy, read carefully! I was talking about `Window.ShowDialog()` not `MessageBox.ShowDialog()`.

Comment: @LarsKristensen , his Question was this: I use a simple Window to show messages. In C# when MessageBox is showing, user can not click or do any thing with another windows. How can I simulate this, in my window? - Wash, Rinse, Repeat for all your other comments.

Comment: @bash.d and all the others; You are right, guess I was a little too quick to correct everyone. But since they have already commented on my comment, I won't remove them - It'll serve as a reminder to me to read questions more carefully in the future :)

Comment: @LarsKristensen it's all right... This can happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.ShowDialog()` to show a modal dialog:

```
MyMsgBox.ShowDialog()
```

This will stop the execution until the message box is closed. See [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx).

Comment: This doesn't address the issue with aligning text as Right-to-Left, which was the reason he is using something other than MessageBox in the first place.

Comment: Actually, that is not the case. The question is about the modal dialog. Read carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Use Window.Showdialog and do not forget to set the Window Parent, or you will get funny behavior.

Then in the Window class have properties for the expected returns, which are filled by the results of the dialog.
Like:

```
public void testDialog()
{
var return = new DialogModelReturn();
mywindow.ShowDialog(new DialogModel(return));

if (return.isOk)
{
}

}
```

Something along this line of thought should work.
Also: I would recommend to set the WindowStyle to none, or at least only a close Button, for the "ModalDialog feeling".

Like this:

```
<Window x:Class="bla.bla"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Fortschritt" Icon="bla.png" Height="200" Width="600"
        WindowStyle="None" Background="RoyalBlue">
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue with aligning text as Right-to-Left.

Comment: That was not his Question, he asked about the Modal Dialog Feature---

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: It seems I didn't read the question carefully, and thought the issue was about not being able to use Right-To-Left alignment in MessageBoxes (which is possible through MessageBoxOptions).

---

There is an overload of the `MessageBox.Show()` method, that lets you specify `MessageBoxOptions`. Some of these options regard right-to-left alignment.

I don't know the language(s) used in Iran, so you'll have to try with your own text, but here is how to specify the options (the last parameter of the method):

```
string message = "Test message.";
string caption = "RTL Test";
MessageBoxImage image = MessageBoxImage.Information;
MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.OK;
MessageBoxResult defaultResult = MessageBoxResult.OK;

MessageBox.Show(message, caption, button, image, defaultResult, MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign);
MessageBox.Show(message, caption, button, image, defaultResult, MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading);
MessageBox.Show(message, caption, button, image, defaultResult, MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading | MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign);
```

Here is a link to an MSDN article about the options: [MessageBoxOptions Enum (Winforms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messageboxoptions.aspx)